# Visual Studio/SQL: Can I have profile-specific Post Deployment scripts?

Tags: visual-studio, database-project

I currently have a SQL Server Database Project and have two profiles for two different clients.

One thing is that we have slightly different database rules for each client, and what I would like to do is to have those created automatically in the Post-deployment script.

What I was hoping for was some way to have an "if profile" where particular commands are executed for one profile or another, but I can't see anything about how to do this. Is there a way, or does anyone have an alternative way to do this in database solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's safe for your clients to see the data for each other, this should work. If not you may have to send them separate scripts to run after the release.

Create a variable that will be used when you release the code (e.g. "DeployType") and use something like this in your post-deploy scripts:

```
IF ( '$(DeployType)' = 'ClientA')
BEGIN
PRINT 'Running Post-Deploy Scripts for Client A'

:r .\ClientA.sql

END
IF ( '$(DeployType)' = 'ClientB')
BEGIN
PRINT 'Running Post-Deploy Scripts for Client B'

:r .\ClientB.sql

END

:r .\Common.sql
```